# Microsoft Word styles changing without my instructions

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, styles

I'm experiencing something very frustrating.

I've got a very long document with various styles for headings, the body etc. I mention its a long document because I don't want to start a new document, which I think might solve my problem.

This first figure shows what I want the piece of text to look like:
[image]

However, Word automatically changes the text to look like this:
[image]

What is happening is that Word is randomly changing the body text to the caption text style. It does this all over the document and when I manually fix it, it does the same thing elsewhere in the document after saving, closing and re-opening the doc.

It always changes the style immediately before a 'Figure' cross-reference. So, the problem lies somewhere with the cross-referencing, Body and Caption styles.

Comment: What does it say when you highlight all of the changed text and right click. Does it say undo? and if so what does it want to Undo?

Comment: The changes are only 'automatically' made when I re-open word. So there is nothing to undo.

Comment: Check out this [Article](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T000997_Preventing_Styles_from_Changing.html) it may be your best bet if you dont want to start over with a new document. You just have to set it up will all the styles you have and it should keep them when you are done.